# Smaller Unit that a Second - Sexagesimal

Tags: time, units, si-units

Most of us seem to measure time HH:mm:ss and then drop into SI prefixes of seconds.

Naturally, this results in a weird swap from base 24 (12 if you're American), to base 60, to base 10 as you progress through the segments.

Which got me wondering... What's smaller than a second in the sexagesimal system, if there even is one?

I suspect there might not be since, as far as I know, there was no way to meaningfully measure units of time smaller than a second before the decimal system was adopted.

Comment: Base 60 was commonly used for various fractional quantities in science. It took centuries for it to be (mostly) replaced by decimal. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal#Other_historical_usages "The sexagesimal number system continued to be frequently used by European astronomers for performing calculations as late as 1671". And 50+ years later it certainly influenced Fahrenheit to create a scale of temperature with 180° between the freezing & boiling points of water. Also see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44126/16685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call it thirds (1/60 th of a second) also fourths would be next (1/60th of a third) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51860/is-there-a-word-for-a-60th-of-a-second